# woocommerce unique order number or invoice number for different products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a WooCommerce web-store which sells four different products.

How can I get different series of order numbers or invoice numbers based on the type of product?

For example: all order IDs or invoice numbers for product 'AA' should start with AA and have a format like AA001, AA002, AA003, AA004...

Similarly, either the order ID or the invoice number for product 'BB' should go like BB001, BB002, BB003 etc.

If this is not possible, I can also live with adding a custom prefix to the invoice number or order number based on the type of product.

For example : invoices / order numbers for product 'AA', 'BB' should include 'AA' or 'BB' as the prefix depending on what is sold.

So my invoice or order number sequence may look like AA001, BB002, CC003, AA004, CC005... i.e. the normal sequence of invoice numbers continues, just the prefix is added.

Edit : Each order will have only one product.

I am bumping my way around in PHP; so any help or pointers on how this can be achieved will be very much appreciated.

Edit 2: The code below is adding a prefix to the order ID everywhere, but I need to get the actual SKU of the order into the prefix field.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    $prefix = 'the product sku should go here';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

Edit 3 : This code works . . .

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item )
    $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    $new_order_id = $sku . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

Edited John's answer below and added a bit of code from here : https://gist.github.com/maxrice/7918315

Comment: What should the order ID look like for orders with more than one product?

Comment: Hi John, each order will have only one product, which simplifies my need.

Comment: @JohnEllmore would be great if you could point me in the right direction. I am getting a generic prefix with the code now, just need to get the SKU (or a tag or any other variable field that will work as the prefix.)

Comment: You mentioned that you need an "order SKU" in another comment. That isn't a thing; only products have SKUs. So you want the SKU from the product in the order, correct?

Comment: @JohnEllmore - Yes Sir. Each order will have only one product, so the SKU of the product needs to go right next to the order number. Right now the SKU is getting displayed in a different table in the (#sku) format, just need it to go right next to the order number, without any other characters. The final order number should look like 'SKU0001'

Comment: Okay, great. The code in my answer below should do that for you.

Comment: I tried the code first thing yesterday, but the checkout gets stuck after adding the code to the wc_template_functions.php file. The checkout page just displays a red band on the top and gets stuck.

Comment: Ah, sorry; I don’t have time to debug. I’d recommend turning on display_errors and adding a `die()` right before the return statement to see what the problem is.

Comment: @JohnEllmore - Thank you for helping me out. I played around a little bit more and edited your original code a bit and it worked. Will update the question to include this answer. Credit goes to you and user 'maxrice' from GitHub for the other code snippet I added to your code : https://gist.github.com/maxrice/7918315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_order_number` filter to accomplish this. Something like this should do the trick (I haven't tested it).

```
function change_woocommerce_order_number($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $first_item = $items[0];
    $product_id = $first_item->get_product_id();
    $product = new WC_Product($product_id);
    $sku = $product->get_sku();

    return $sku.$order_id;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number');
```

Comment: Thanks John, will try it out and see if it works. Looks very promising.

Comment: The code below is adding a prefix to the order ID everywhere, but I need to get the actual SKU of the order into the prefix field.

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

    function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
        $prefix = 'the product sku should go here';
        $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
        return $new_order_id;
    }